# Python Script it not showing more than 1 page of results of Shopify Orders

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, shopify

I’m having some hard time trying to make this code shows more than 1 page of orders.

I already tried different methods, such as loops and also the one below (which is just a workaround) where I tried to get the page 2.

I just need it to brings me all the orders generated in a specific day - but I got completely stuck.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Set the API token for the Shopify API

api_token = 'MYTOKEN'

# Get the current date and subtract one day

today = datetime.now()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)

# Format the date strings for the API request

start_date = yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00Z')
end_date = yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT23:59:59Z')

# Set the initial limit to 1

limit = 1
page_info = 2

# Set the initial URL for the API endpoint you want to access, including the limit and date range parameters

url = f'https://MYSTORE.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/orders.json?page_info=%7Bpage_info%7D&limit=%7Blimit%7D&created_at_min=%7Bstart_date%7D&created_at_max=%7Bend_date%7D&'

# Set the API token as a header for the request

headers = {'X-Shopify-Access-Token': api_token}

# Make the GET request

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Check the status code of the response

if response.status_code == 200:

    # Parse the JSON response directly
    orders = response.json()['orders']
    
    # Flatten the JSON response into a Pandas DataFrame, including the 'name' column (order number) and renaming the 'id' column to 'order_id'
    df = pd.json_normalize(orders, sep='_', record_path='line_items', meta=['name', 'id'], meta_prefix='meta_')
    
    # Flatten the line_items data into a separate DataFrame
    line_items_df = pd.json_normalize(orders, 'line_items', ['id'], meta_prefix='line_item_')
    
    # Flatten the 'orders' data into a separate | Added in Dec.26-2022
    orders_df = pd.json_normalize(orders, sep='_', record_path='line_items', meta=['created_at', 'id'], meta_prefix='ordersDTbs_')
    
    # Merge the 'df' and 'orders_df' DataFrames | Added in Dec.26-2022
    df = pd.merge(df, orders_df[['id', 'ordersDTbs_created_at']], on='id')
    
    # Converting create_at date to DATE only | Added in Dec.26-2022
    df['ordersDTbs_created_at'] = df['ordersDTbs_created_at'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').date())
    
    # Concatenate the two dataframes
    df = pd.merge(df, line_items_df[['id', 'sku', 'quantity']], on='id')
    
    # Calculate the discount amount and add it as a new column in the dataframe
    df['price_set_shop_money_amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price_set_shop_money_amount'])
    df['total_discount_set_shop_money_amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['total_discount_set_shop_money_amount'])
    df = df.assign(paid_afterdiscount=df['price_set_shop_money_amount'] - df['total_discount_set_shop_money_amount'])
    
    # Print the DataFrame
    print(df[['meta_name','ordersDTbs_created_at','sku_y','title','fulfillable_quantity','quantity_x','quantity_y','paid_afterdiscount']])
    
    #Checking if API ran smoothly

else:
print('Something went wrong.')
```

I already tried different methods, such as loops and also the one below (which is just a workaround) where I tried to get the page 2.

Comment: You're using `requests` to fetch the page, which does not process javascript.

Comment: I tried to remove ‘import requests' and run it again, but it stills not working as expected. The code returns me the "Something went wrong.” message now (which is checking the URL response).

Comment: If you're not using `requests` to fetch the page anymore, what are you using instead?

Comment: Actually I just removed and ran it again. What I don’t get is why when I run the code without the page commands it works, but then when I add it the code breaks.

For example, if I just change the first part of the code as below, it runs and returns me the 1st page orders, but when I specify other pages it just stop working.

Comment: import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta […]
[…] # Set the initial limit to 1
limit = 1

# Set the initial URL for the API endpoint you want to access, including the limit and date range parameters
url = f'https://MYSTORE.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/orders.json?limit={limit}&created_at_min={start_date}&created_at_max={end_date}&’